# Is there a reference for Lois Lane's hammer?

Tags: reference, arrowverse

In the Arrowverse crossover "Elseworlds" we see Lois Lane wielding a large hammer during the fight with the *evil* Superman/Deegan.

[image]

The hammer is first seen at the entrance to the Fortress of Solitude on Earth-38...

[image]

Given the number of references and easter eggs in the multi-episode crossover, I'm struggling to find a reference for this hammer.

It *could* be the hammer of John Henry "Steel" Irons but it does not seem to approximate the look of that object.

Is there a Arrowverse or comics reference for "Superman's Hammer" of which I am unaware

Comment: FWIW it is [not Thor's hammer](https://tvline.com/2018/12/08/arrowverse-crossover-preview-elizabeth-tulloch-lois-lane-superman-interview/): _"I don’t know that I can. But I will say that a lot of the fans seem to think its Thor’s hammer, and I’m like, “Well, no because isn’t that Marvel?” So, I guess all I can say it’s not Thor’s hammer, but you know it’s still a badass hammer. They’ll just have to wait and see."_

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Thanks for that, I wasn't aware of that article, must have missed it (perhaps I was avoiding spoilers! :)

Comment: That's the only thing I found in a quick search, a lot of other articles speculate it could be the hammer of John Henry "Steel" Irons as you do but nothing official.

Comment: Cosplay Thor's hammer?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, the actress playing Lois Lane, Elizabeth Tulloch, asked the producers the same question and received an answer via Twitter.

> A lot of people have been asking me about the hammer Lois carries so I texted Robert Rovner co-showrunner/EP of #Supergirl for clarification and he said, “It’s the solar hammer from the cosmic anvil.” Hope that clears up any confusion.

[image]

> The Solar Hammer that is paired with the Cosmic Anvil - two items depicted in Superman's workshop in [**All-Star Superman**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-Star_Superman). Reportedly he uses The Solar Hammer and Cosmic Anvil to forge tiny suns to feed the baby Sun-Eater he keeps as a pet.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://screenrant.com/elseworlds-arrowverse-crossover-unanswered-questions/)</sup>

[image]